PHPStan and Laravel request()
Faced upgrading phpstan to the max level and there was a problem with the request() helper.
I fixed the bug by extracting the request() helper into a variable and adding an annotation, but for me it's not pretty and I need to duplicate code not needed.
example:
was
$extension = request()->get('extension') ?? $user->extension->name ?? null;

became
/** @var Request $request */
$request = request();

$extension = $request->get('extension') ?? $user->extension->name ?? null;

or better way is to remove this verification from phpstan config?

inject the request in your controller method. if you are using the request() helper anywhere else, then stop doing that.
